# Djando. Действие после добавления объекта (post_add)

Tags: django

Можно ли в Django сделать так что бы при добавлении экземпляра связанной модели изменялось поле модели?

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    is_sorted = models.BooleanField()

class Gymnast(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Competition, related_name='gymnasts')
    name = models.CharField()
```

Требуется при добавлении (удалении) экземпляра **Гимнаст** изменять поле *is_sorted* связанного класса **Соревнование**. При этом что бы при изменении полей экземпляра **Гимнаст** (например *name*) поле *is_sorted* для класса **Соревнование** не менялось.
Вроде есть сигнал *post_add*, но он как я понимаю для связей ManyToMany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для обработки действий после удаления объекта и/или после его создания, имеются сигналы [`post_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-delete) и [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save)

Метод `post_save` принимает параметр `created`. `created` указывает создан ли новый объект или был изменен старый.

По параметру `instance` можно получить связанный объект `Competition`.

Обратите внимание, что при on_delete=CASCADE связанный объект будет удалён.